I bricked my LUKS partition, how do I recover it?
I bricked my LUKS partition. Now I want to recover my partition or files.
How I bricked my partiton:

I was resizing my BTRFS LUKS2 main partition from a live boot environment. It was taking very long so I terminated the partitioning application.

Now my main partition is marked as "unformated" in my partition manager, and I can no longer boot into my main system

This is my lsblk output
 nvme0n1     259:0    0 238.5G  0 disk 
├─nvme0n1p1 259:1    0   600M  0 part 
├─nvme0n1p2 259:2    0     1G  0 part 
└─nvme0n1p5 259:3    0   207G  0 part 


P5 is my main partition, so im assuming my data is in p5 and the rest of the drive isn't allocated to any file system.



not enough info by far... what did you do? which partitioning application? cryptsetup luksDump?

if no luks header can be found you can try cryptsetup repair but if you were moving data around in e.g. gparted and you canceled that, it won't help. if data is at the wrong offsets then cryptsetup will decrypt it all wrong and it will look like random data instead...

@frostschutz I used KDE partition manager, I showed in the attached pictures what I was trying to do https://cdn1.filehaus.su/files/1721031887_10378/Screenshot_20240715_042004.png https://cdn6.filehaus.su/files/1721031931_20154/Screenshot_20240715_041926.png, the picture labled with 1, being the before state, and the other picture is what my partitions currently look like, the reason I moved my main partition around was to merge another empty un-allocated partitions together

user626125 please put that in your question. Information in comments can be lost or (occasionally) even deleted

so the partition was moved; and the move cancelled? recovery in this case depends on the move algorithm. I don't know KDE partition manager (or parted, for that matter) well enough to judge how to proceed here. If this program does not keep a progress / offer a resume feature, it might be difficult.

@frostschutz I would bet real money it won't be possible.
